# Accessing the blank.test.com cookies from www.blank.test.com in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, cookies, subdomain

I'm having a problem accessing cookies from the www domain of my website, and it needs to be fixed in the JavaScript.

Don't know if it's possible.

The summary is that I want to delete cookies from this.is.it.com from JavaScript running on www.this.is.it.com, but targeting any other domain results in a leading dot like this:

```
.this.is.it.com
```

Here's the code.

```
function deleteTheCookies(){


if(document.domain == "www.this.is.it.com"){

    document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";path=/";  


}

if(document.domain == "this.is.it.com"){
    document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";path=/";  

}

}
```

So far, only if I call this function from the www domain it will delete the www version of the cookies, and if I call it from the NON www domain it will delete the NON www cookies. Which makes sense.

However, I want to delete the NON www cookies from the WWW domain.

I've tried the following:

```
if(document.domain == "www.this.is.it.com"){

document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";path=/"; 

document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";domain=this.is.it.com" + ";path=/";

}
```

The **above** (specifically setting the domain in document.cookie) results in the OUTPUT cookie having a *leading dot*

```
.this.is.it.com
```

This doesn't delete the cookie I'm trying to target, as the target is

```
this.is.it.com
```

I have also tried the following

```
if(document.domain == "www.this.is.it.com"){

    document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";path=/"; 


    document.domain = "this.is.it.com"                                                           // changes to NON www

    document.cookie = "nameOfCookie=" + ";expires=Fri Jun 03 2000 14:24:58 GMT-0400" + ";path=/"; 

}
```

as well as trying the above with the domain specified

i.e.

```
";domain=this.is.it.com"
```

Regardless, the output from the www still always points to

```
.this.is.it.com
```

Not quite sure where to go from here, but this function *needs* to be called from the www site, and I can't call it from both.

Is this possible?

Comment: If there's a cookie in both `www.domain` and `domain`, the more specific one hides the less specific one. There's no way to access the cookie from the parent domain when it's hidden like this.

Comment: You should fix the code that's creating the cookie in the subdomain. It should create the cookie in the parent domain, and then it will be visible in all subdomains, and they will be able to delete it.